# Getting RouteData in a Controller's constructor/attributes to route [Authorize]'s ConnectionString

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership, routedata

**Background**

I have a multitenant application that uses multiple databases per-tenant.  I'm using CodeFirstMembership, so I have full controll over the SimpleMembership implementation.  Both my User/Role entities are in the same DbContext as the rest of my application.

**The Problem**

In order to facilitate multi-tenance, I have a custom route that looks exactly the same as what the default vanilla MVC route looks like, with the exception that I grab the subdomain, check it against the tenants that have an account, and grab their specific connection string.  I have an extension method on the RouteData called .GetSubdomain() that will return the subdomain used, so I can really do the check and get the connection string wherever, if that helps you with your answer.

I need my membership provider to be able to access the subdomain check information in order to point to the correct database for the [Authorize] method to work correctly.

**What I've tried**

- **Initializing the membership provider in the InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute**

  - This didn't work because you can't pass in dynamic parameters into attributes (like RouteData.GetSubdomain())
- **Initializing the membership in the constructor.**

  - While you can call RouteData methods in the constructor and have the app build/run, RouteData has not been populated at the point of the constructor in a controller, so this method didn't work either.
- **I didn't try this, but adding the check at the start of each controller method is likely not to work since the authorization has already ran.**

**So...**
Out of what I've tried, it seems like I need to hook into the point between where RouteData is populated and the actual Authorization.  Is there a point I can do this effectively?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

WOW.  In a total oversight, I failed to see the `ActionExecutingContext` that was being passed into the InitializeSimpleMembership attribute.  The context being passed in actually contains RouteData, and the subdomain information needed to properly initialize the membership!